# Could Not Deactivate Swap in Gparted Error

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I'm trying to partition my Linux VM (VirtualBox on MacBook Air) using GParted after clicking `Try Ubuntu`(I didn't install Ubuntu yet). This is my GParted setup:

[image: GParted]

After right clicking, I clicked the `swapoff` option on `/dev/sda5` and I got this error message:

[image: error message]

I have plenty of space in my VM but I don't know why it isn't working and I'd appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Edit: This is the output of `free`:

[image: free]

Comment: Based on the error that you got I would assume that there isn't enough RAM allocated to the VM to turn off swap. the output of `free` would help confirm

Comment: How would allocate enough RAM to the VM?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `free`. Issue this command from a terminal session within the VM. You can typically open one with the CTRL-ALT-T key combination.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/264063/resize-partitions-gparted-swapoff-fail?rq=1

Comment: I edited the question to include the `free` output. I also looked at the related link but I'm not running GParted from a LiveUSB, I'm only using the `Try Ubuntu` option, so I haven't actually installed Ubuntu yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the free mem: line with the swap: used line and you can see that there isn't enough available RAM to turn swap off.

**Edit:** The maximum RAM available  is free mem + cached but in this case it doesn't matter as the combination of the 2 still is less than swap in use.

You will need to increase the amount of RAM available to the VM. You do this in the setting for the machine in the manager by moving the Base memory pointer or keying in a higher value in the box to the right of the pointer as below:

[image: VM Manger]